# How to do swap the order of div elements in response to media queries?

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a twitter clone, and I am attempting to style the signup page. So far, I am using css grid to order to main divs, with two columns on wide screens, and two rows on narrow screens.

On a wide screen, I would like the two divs to remain in one row, with the **bird logo div** being on the **left**, and the **sign up form** on the **right**. On screens narrower than 900px, I want the **sign up form** to remain at the **top**, and the **bird logo div** to remain at the **bottom**. How do I accomplish this? When shifting from columns to rows, I need some way to swap the order in which the div occurs.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.signup{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.left-side{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.right-side{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.bird{
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .signup{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        grid-template-rows: 80% auto;
        height: 140vh;
        background-color: cadetblue;
    }

  
}
```

```html
  <div class="signup">
      <div class="left-side">
          <img src="" alt="bird" class="bird"/>
      </div>
      <div class="right-side">
          <h1>Sign up!</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid-area` works fine for that

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.signup{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "form" "bird";
    height: 100vh;
}

.form {
    grid-area: form;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.bird {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: bird;
    place-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.bird-img{
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 901px) {
    .signup {
        grid-template-areas: "bird form";
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .signup{
        grid-template-rows: 80% auto;
        height: 140vh;
        background-color: cadetblue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="signup">
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Sign up!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bird">
        <img src="" alt="bird" class="bird-img"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I renamed `.left-side` and `.right-side` to match areas names

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good candidate for `display:flex` with `order`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.signup,
.bird {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
}

.signup {
  background: papayawhip;
  order: 1
}

.bird {
  background: aqua
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="signup">
    Signup
  </div>
  <div class="bird">
    bird
  </div>
</div>
```